# codeigniter: one controller several actions

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, frameworks

I'm using codeigniter. I'm currently working on my routes and controller.
Last week, I explored symfony2 and I liked something:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('LVIndexBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function servicesAction()
    {
        return $this->render('LVIndexBundle:Default:services.html.twig');
    }

    public function shoppingAction()
    {
        return $this->render('LVIndexBundle:Default:services.html.twig');
    }
```

In the controller, each action renders a view.

I would like to do the same in codeigniter -> get several functions / actions leading to distinct views.

I'm new to codeigniter. So far, I understood that 1 controller = 1 view.
I'd like to get 1 controller = several functions for several pages. Otherwise, that would be a lot of pages.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: My first approach with a framework has been Codeigniter but after exploring the Symfony's world I immediately migrated my project on it. After some months I realized that many problems I encountered with my project would been more problematic to resolve in CI. Symfony gives you much more power and flexibility based on a strong OOP Patterns foundation (implemented at a "state of the art" level).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience(s):

In CI, a **controller** can has more than 1 **view** php file

**ex** (function indexAction as a controller function):

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('content');
   $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: I know that it is possible to get several views in a function.

Comment: My question was rather how to get several functions in a controller:
page 1, page 2, page 3...

Comment: You have fair [instruction](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html#adding-logic-to-the-controller) of how to create pages. There can be concluded of similar system you showed from Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony and Codeigniter the controllers are just classes that can hold multiple methods. The methods that are called (called Actions in Symfony) are the place that decides which view(s) must be rendered. One of the main differences between Symfony and CI controllers are the routings that Symfony uses. The routes makes Symfony more flexible then CI.

[take a look for an explanation of CI controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#what)

p.s. Symfony is much more advanced then CI. I like to advise you Symfony :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutely not true that there should be one view per controller. even something as simple as validating a form - you will call different views depending on if the validation passes or not.

Strongly suggest you step through the Tutorial in the codeigniter manual. this is going to answer a lot of questions and its very practical.